# How to make Ignite act non-blocking with TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder like it does with TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder?

Tags: java, jelastic, ignite

**Background**:

- I have a web app, spring-based.
- locally on a dev machine I have 2 tomcat instances that runs same app - that way I test how web farm nodes communicates to each other
- I use Jelastic cloud for app deployment
- On Jelastic It's not running as a web-farm, but rolling update mechanism is used (while `AppV1` is running at `NodeA` and handling user requsts I start `AppV2@NodeB`, warm it up and redirect user requests to it. Goal is to let `NodeB` copy all sessions from `NodeA`)

**Intention**

- Current release version is using 3rd server based on NodeJS as a shortcut to MessageBus between nodes. But recently I spotted Ignite and thought it would be great to decrease number of platforms (nodejs) and get just everything in Java.
- So I replaced NodeJS-based messaging with Ignite messaging. Ignite is initialized using Spring XML config and `org.apache.ignite.IgniteSpringBean`
- When running my app locally with `TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder` it works perfectly. `NodeA` starts even if there is no `NodeB` started. When I start `NodeB` it smoothly joins cluster and nodes are connected to each other and communicating perfectly. Most important thing here is that I can start and stop nodes any time and I have non-blocking error-free operation using Ignite messaging.

**Issue**

- But on Jelastic I don't have multicast, so I have to explicitly define list of IP addresses (use `TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder`), which is ok - I have kind of static host names for each node. **BUT** now when `NodeA` starts it blocks until it connects to `NodeB`. And if `NodeB` is not there whole app crash (failes to deploy).

**Question is**
How to make it work in scenario

1. `TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder` is used
2. `NodeA` starts (while `NodeB` is not started)
3. Expectation: `NodeA` operates any amount of time correctly (of course I can't send messages to remotes, because there are no remotes connected - that is ok)
4. At any time `NodeB` starts
5. Expectation: `NodeA` and `NodeB` find each other and communicate to each other (basically for sessions replication and other messages)
6. `NodeA` stopped
7. Expectation: `NodeB` continues to operate normally serving user requests
8. Now switch: `NodeA` becomes `NodeB` and vice versa; repeat from step 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you missed one important thing related to `TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder`. Both nodes A and B have to contain their own IP addresses in the IP finder's addresses list. This is highlighted in this readme section [1].
Otherwise you'll get into the situation like you have when node A has to wait while node B joins the cluster.

Set this IP finder for both the nodes and everything should work as required.

```
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                    <property name="addresses">
                        <list>
                            <value>hodeA_ip_address_or_host_name:47500..47509</value>
                            <value>hodeB_ip_address_or_host_name:47500..47509</value>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
```

[1] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config#static-ip-based-discovery

Answer (score 0):

I found workaround (not a solution). If you know right solution - please let me know by adding answer below.

I subclassed `TcpDiscoverySpi` and override `resolvedAddresses()` in order to test candidates whether they are reachable or not.

That solution is not perfect because now if `NodeA` didn't find `NodeB` it will never retry to find `NodeB`. However that is not a showstopper since once `NodeB` starts it reaches `NodeA` and they start talking to each other. So effectively Rolling Updates mechanism works for me.

Method `isCandidateRespond` is quick-n-dirty solution and most likely will vary case-by-case.

Here is a code snippet:

```
public class TcpDiscoverySpiPrecheckingImpl extends TcpDiscoverySpi {
    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    protected Collection<InetSocketAddress> resolvedAddresses() throws IgniteSpiException {
        Collection<InetSocketAddress> candidates = super.resolvedAddresses();
        Collection<InetSocketAddress> approved = new ArrayList<>();
        for (InetSocketAddress candidate : candidates) {
            if (isCandidateRespond(candidate)) {
                approved.add(candidate);
            }
        }
        return approved;
    }

    private boolean isCandidateRespond(InetSocketAddress candidate) {
        if (log.isTraceEnabled()) {
            log.trace("Checking if remote node responds: " + candidate);
        }
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://" + candidate.getHostName() + "/");
            try (InputStream stream = url.openStream()) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            log.info("Candidate remote node didn't respond: " + url + ". Reason: " + t.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```